# Is it possible to call a Python function from Julia and return its result?

Tags: python, julia

I am using Python to scrape data from the web. I want to use that data to run calculations in Julia.

Is it possible to call the function in Julia and return its result, or am I better off just exporting to a CSV and loading the data in that way?

Answer (score 18):

Absolutely.  See [PyCall.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl).

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> @pyimport bs4

julia> @pyimport requests

julia> r = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638265");

julia> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content);

julia> soup.title.string
"Is it possible to call a Python function from Julia and return its result? - Stack Overflow"

julia> soup.select_one(".answercell p").text
"Absolutely.  See PyCall.jl."
```

Comment: Love that you're scraping this very question! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question, but it is rather easy to scrape web in Julia itself

```
using Gumbo
using Cascadia
using Cascadia: matchFirst
using HTTP

r = HTTP.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638265")
page = parsehtml(String(r.body))
```

```
julia> matchFirst(sel"title", page.root) |> nodeText
"Is it possible to call a Python function from Julia and return its result? - Stack Overflow"

julia> eachmatch(sel".answercell p", page.root) .|> nodeText
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "Absolutely.  See PyCall.jl."
 "Not an answer to your question, but it is rather easy to scrape web in Julia itself"
```